# SQL for the wordpress database

Tags: sql

I need some help with an SQL query, im a bit rusty with this. The Wordpress database im using is set up like this.

```
post_id, meta_key, meta_value
33, opt_in, 1
33, email, john@hotmail.com
```

how can i collect all email address' where the opt in has the value of '1', the post_id is what matches the two rows. I have looked at sql union, and this the closest I have got.

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='opt_in' AND meta_value='1'
UNION
SELECT meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='email'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with JOIN

```
SELECT p2.meta_value email
  FROM wp_postmeta p1 JOIN wp_postmeta p2
    ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id
   AND p1.meta_key = 'opt_in'
   AND p2.meta_key = 'email'
 WHERE p1.meta_value = 1
```

If you were to have

```
| POST_ID | META_KEY |        META_VALUE |
|---------|----------|-------------------|
|      33 |   opt_in |                 1 |
|      33 |    email |  john@hotmail.com |
|      34 |   opt_in |                 0 |
|      34 |    email | helen@hotmail.com |
|      35 |   opt_in |                 1 |
|      35 |    email |  mark@hotmail.com |
```

Query output would be:

```
|            EMAIL |
|------------------|
| john@hotmail.com |
| mark@hotmail.com |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2abf/3)** demo

Comment: Really detailed answer, Thnakyou

Answer (score 1):

i think what you need is the `meta_value` field, not `post_id`

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'email' AND
      post_id = (SELECT post_id 
                 FROM wp_postmeta 
                 WHERE meta_key = 'opt_in' AND
                       meta_value = 1)
```

Comment: That was the exact query I needed, I forgot you could put whole queries inside brackets like that. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 1):

```
select meta_value 
from wp_postmeta w1
where meta_key = 'email'
and exists (select 1 from wp_postmeta w2 where w1.post_id = w2.post_id and w2.meta_key = 'opt_in' and meta_value = 1)
```

or

```
select w1.meta_value 
from wp_postmeta w1
inner join wp_postmeta w2 on w1.post_id = w2.post_id
and w1.meta_key = 'email' 
and w2.meta_key = 'opt_in' and w2.meta_value = 1
```